# Two distinct mount points with one device

Tags: linux, mount

After being disappointed with Ubuntu's release update feature, I finally decided to have separate mount points for `/` and `/home`.

Towards this, I reformatted my HDD giving most of my drive to `sda1`(meant to be `/home`) and allocated about 40GB to rootfs (`/`).
Unfortunately, I would also like to have a `/projects` which is to be located on sda1.

Currently, `sda1` is being mounted as
`/dev/sda1 on /home type ext4 (rw)`
I've tried looking online for a solution to this problem..however, I'm not sure as to what to look for!

Is it possible to mount the 'home' directory of `sda1` as `/home` and 'projects' directory of `sda1` as `/projects`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use a **bind mount**:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /home
mkdir /home/projects
mount -t none -o bind /home/projects /projects
```

You can also put these in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sda1       /home      ext4 defaults  1 2
/home/projects  /projects  none bind      0 0
```

The **rbind** option is needed to make submounts visible, for example because `/projects/apollo` is on a separate partition. **ro** can be used to mount it read-only.

More details are available in the [mount(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) man page, in the "Bind mount operation" section.

Comment: In the last code line, don't you mean /home/projects rather than just /home?

Answer (score 4):

Step 1) Create a projects directory in the home folder.

Step 2) Create a symlink to this new directory from root.

```
mkdir /home/projects
ln -s /home/projects /projects
```

Comment: soft-links! If only I had thought of that! :|   
Thanks!

Comment: Just a small follow up: This solution works quite well. The only downside to it is that you cannot run some linux utilities without including additional options to follow symlinks. For example, you cannot run `find` without including `-follow`.